# Add css to svg with inkscape

Tags: css, svg, inkscape

I use Inkscape for creating svg images and want to know how to use not embedded css rules.

For example

- draw rectangle
- in XML-editor add class attribute as

> class="rect1"
>   
>   to *svg:rect* object

How to add css like

> .rect1 {
>     fill:#ffef00;
>   }

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's an example of an SVG in an HTML page that you can style with CSS:

**HTML page**

```
<div id="mySvg">
  <svg>
    <use xlink:href="images/logo.svg#shape" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

**The SVG (located at images/logo.svg)**

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <g id="shape">
        <rect x="50" y="50" width="50" height="50" />
        <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" />
    </g>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

**The CSS**

```
svg {
    fill: currentColor;
}

#mySvg {
    color: green;
}
```

See working example: [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/i8RFDW?p=preview)

**Notes**

- If you use Inkscape to create your SVG, you'll probably have to do some hand-editing of the SVG to make it styleable with CSS.
- Make sure the SVG code doesn't have any `fill` attributes in it (`fill` should be in the CSS). When making an SVG with Inkscape, it often has a `fill:none` or something. You'll have to manually remove those.
- When using Inkscape, save files as "Optimized SVG" as described [here](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Web-Inkscape.html).